# Lwuit vs j2me-polish? and What is the advantages of LWUIT with respect to J2ME-Polish?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, mobile-application, j2mepolish

Now, we plan for developing a mobile application using j2me.

For UI, we go for a framework like **LWUIT,J2me-polish**,etc.

Finally we decide for **LWUIT or J2me-polish.**

My choice is **LWUIT** and my colligues choice is **J2ME-Polish**

We want to choose anyone from them. So please give your ideas regarding **LWUIT,J2ME-Polish**,

Advantages of **LWUIT.**

How **LWUIT** is better than **J2ME-Polish**,etc.

My opinion is both **J2ME & LWUIT** are the **sun's (Oracle)** product. So both matches very well.IF we have any issues regarding integration of j2me and lwuit means then the ideas we get from oracle forum/site,etc.

J2me polish is Enough product.So i think it have some restrictions,disadvantages,etc with J2me.

I don't know whether my above point is correct or not. Please mention ur opinions about the above points also

All are welcome to give their ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both LWUIT & j2me polish provide good GUI facility which was once missed in j2me. Both supports 500+ different phones models, as it will face in real market. My opinion is to use LWUIT, sun is giving lot more support for the LWUIT. J2ME Polish is has lesser chance in covering most number of handsets in the market.
You can also have a look on [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?147024-J2ME-Polish-or-LWUIT-or-what-for-commercial-J2ME-software) and [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=7106023) thread. They have some discussion about LWUIT vs. J2ME Polish.

Comment: Ur answer is very usefull.But i need it more.So only im not tick choose for correct answer.Due to its usefullness im incrementing ur answers point.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the links from Abdullah are somewhat outdated. Effectively both LWUIT & AFAIK J2ME Polish are effectively dead end technologies (disclaimer I'm one of the founders of LWUIT).

Both take radically different approaches: LWUIT tries to unify all devices while Polish uses Macros to workaround the differences.

Since both Chen and myself left Sun/Oracle and no longer maintain LWUIT it probably won't see significant progress or support. We are now developing [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which has LWUIT roots but goes much further. However, if your only target is older J2ME devices/networks that might not be the best direction for you.